# How to write regular expression to find combination of characters, but each can only appear once in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find whether "xy" in a string, "xy" is optional, for each character it can only appear once. For example:

```
def findpat(texts, pat):
    for text in texts:
        if re.search(pat, t):
            print re.search(pat, t).group()
        else:
            print None    

pat = re.compile(r'[xy]*?b')
text = ['xyb', 'xb', 'yb', 'yxb','b', 'xyxb']
findpat(text, pat)

# it prints
# xyb
# xb
# yb
# yxb
# b
# xyxb
```

For the last one, my desired output is "yxb". 
How should I modify my regex? Many thanks

Comment: Only these 2 characters, x and y.

Comment: Wait, I get a different output: https://ideone.com/JSLMVT. Did you actually use `*` instead of `?`?

Comment: Please check [this demo](https://ideone.com/UkXNBN).

Comment: See my answer, it is a generic solution supporting any number of chars in the ranges/sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern

```
r'(x?y?|yx)b'
```

To break down, the interesting part `x?y?|yx` will match:

1. empty string
2. only x
3. only y
4. xy
5. and on the alternative branch, yx

As an advice, when you aren't very comfortable with regex and your number of scenarios are small, you could simply brute force the pattern. It's ugly, but it makes clear what your cases are:

```
r'b|xb|yb|xyb|yxb'
```

---

**Part 2.**

For a generic solution, that will do the same, but for any number of characters instead of just *{x, y}*, the following regex style can be used:

```
r'(?=[^x]*x?[^x]*b)(?=[^y]*y?[^y]*b)(?=[^z]*z?[^z]*b)[xyz]*b'
```

I'll explain it a bit:

- By using lookaheads you advance the regex cursor and for each position, you just "look ahead" and see if what follows respects a certain condition. By using this technique, you may combine several conditions into a single regex.
- For a cursor position, we test each character from our set to appear at most once from the position, until we match our target *b* character. We do this with this pattern `[^x]*x?[^x]*`, which means *match not-x if there are any, match at most one x, then match any number of not x*
- Once the test conditions are met, we start advancing the cursor and matching all the characters from our needed set, until we find a *b*. At this point we are guaranteed that we won't match any duplicates, because we performed our lookahead tests.

Note: I strongly suspect that this has poor performance, because it does backtracking. You should only use it for small test strings.

[Test it.](https://ideone.com/pvh6Lt)

Comment: Because I need to handle more characters later, so the combinations will be too heavy to handle.

Comment: Then add this detail to the question, because the solution may be different if you have a large number of characters.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following approach: match and capture the two groups, `([xy]*)(b)`. Then, once a match is found, check if the length of the value in Group 1 is the same as the number of unique chars in this value. If not, remove the chars from the start of the group value until you get a string with the length of the number of unique chars.

Something like:

```
def findpat(texts, pat):
    for t in texts:
        m = re.search(pat, t)                   # Find a match
        if m:
            tmp = set([x for x in m.group(1)])  # Get the unqiue chars
            if len(tmp) == len(m.group(1)):     # If Group 1 length is the same
                print re.search(pat, t).group() # Report a whole match value
            else:
                res = m.group(1)
                while len(tmp) < len(res):      # While the length of the string is not
                    res = res[1:]               # equal to the number of unique chars, truncate from the left
                print "{}{}".format(res, m.group(2)) # Print the result
        else:
            print None               # Else, no match

pat = re.compile(r'([xy]*)(b)')
text = ['xyb', 'xb', 'yb', 'yxb','b', 'xyxb']
findpat(text, pat)
# => [xyb, xb, yb, yxb, b, yxb]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2GEI34)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the regexp that literally passes your test cases is:

```
 pat = re.compile(r'(x|y|xy|yx)?b$')
```

where the "$" anchors the string at the end and thereby ensures it's the last match found.

However it's a little more tricky to use the regexp mechanism(s) to ensure that only one matching character from the set is used ...

Answer (score 0):

From [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew)'s comment & [demo](https://ideone.com/UkXNBN), I got my answer.

```
pat = re.compile(r'([xy]?)(?:(?!\1)[xy])?b')
```

Thanks you all!